Network printer not working, address (null) when trying to use it with Fedora 40 workstation
I have an EPSON WorkForce PRO WF-6590 printer. It says it can print over the network but, sadly, I'm unable to make it work.
I have a Fedora 40 Workstation (GNOME 46.4) and when I start my session I can see the network printer. It is detected automatically, but the address of the printer is (null).
Is there a way I can make it work? Maybe some of the configuration on the printer itself to allow to see the network address?



Most Epson printers require proprietary drivers. Have you installed them?  If not: http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=PT&CN2=&DSCMI=156882&DSCCHK=52b8964fc092b5605466f4e9b9aaa4feb10e533a

I tried but it keeps not working, the NULL adress part keeps appearing
